# Successor topology

Tags: general-topology, compactness

EDIT: I answered it myself below, please upvote it if you agree.

Let $X = \mathbb{N}$ and let the topology equipped be given via

$$\tau=\{U \subset \mathbb{N} : (2n-1) \in U \Rightarrow 2n \in U\}$$

Show $(X,\tau)$ is locally compact but not compact.

For locally compact, I need to have a compact set containing an open set containing any given $x \in \mathbb{N}$

So does this split into cases where $x \in \mathbb{N}$ is even or is odd? If $x \in \mathbb{N}$ is even, can we take my open neighborhood to be $\{x\}$ and if $x \in \mathbb{N}$ is odd then $\{x,x+1\}$ can be my $U$? and my compact set containing it can be $\{x,x+1,x+2,x+3\}$?

And for not compact do I take an arbitrary open covering, say

$$\mathbb{N} \subseteq \bigcup_{\alpha \in A} U_\alpha$$

where $A$ is an arbitrary indexing set, and show it has no finite sub covering? could I do this by contradiction? Suppose there exists a finite subset $B \subset A$ such that
$$\mathbb{N} \subset \bigcup_{\beta \in B} U_\beta$$

Am I on the right path?

Comment: My usual advice when faced with an unfamiliar topology like this is to investigate some examples of open sets, closed sets, and sets which are neither. Can you think of at least two examples each in the three categories? It's important to develop some intuition for the topology first, before you launch into proofs. You can think about compactness too, but (hint) finite sets are automatically compact.

Comment: So is $\{1,2\}$ open and $\{3,4,5,...\}$ closed (since its the complement of the first) and $\{1,2,3\}$ neither? @TheoBendit EDIT: the second set is both closed and open?

Comment: Indeed (and note that the first set is also closed and open)! Note that $\{1, 2\}$ is an open neighbourhood of both $1$ and $2$, and is compact, since it is finite. Can you generalise this to prove local compactness? Also, you should think about non-compactness. Can you find a *specific* cover of $\Bbb{N}$ with open sets (hint: make them small) which has no finite subcover?

Comment: can I union together $\{n,n+1\}$? which is an open cover of $\mathbb{N}$ as $n$ ranges over the naturals? but has no finite sub cover? @TheoBendit

Comment: Close. Note that, for example, $\{2, 3\}$ is not open.

Comment: hmm good point @TheoBendit let me think..

Comment: @TheoBendit I think I got locally compact. For $x \in \mathbb{N}$ even take $U:=\{x,x+1,x+2\}$ and $K :=\{x,x+1,x+2,x+3\}$ then $U \subset K$ and $K$ is finite thus compact. For $x \in \mathbb{N}$ odd take $U:=\{x,x+1\}$ and $K:=\{x,x+1,x+2\}$ am I correct? my $K$ need not be open.

Comment: Yes, this looks good! Of course, your $K$ need not be open, but then again, it need not *not* be open. Every set you specified there is finite, and hence compact, so you could just take $K = U$ instead.

Comment: Also for the other part, the compactness can I take $\{2n-1,2n\}$as $n$ ranges through the naturals? @TheoBendit

Comment: Yes! That's what I had in mind. You can show, not only does it not have a finite subcover, but it doesn't even have a proper subcover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For locally compact:

Let $x \in \mathbb{N}$, if $x$ is even, then take

$$U:=\{x\}$$

and to find a set properly containing it take our compact set to be the finite set

$$K:=\{x,x+1\}.$$

If $x$ is odd, then take

$$U:=\{x,x+1\}$$

and

$$K:=\{x,x+1,x+2\}$$

Then we have found a compact set containing the open set containing each point of $\mathbb{N}$, and thus $(X,\tau)$ is locally compact.

For not compact, take the open cover

$$\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \{2n-1,2n\}$$

which has no finite sub cover. If it did, then there would exists a finite subset $A \subset \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$\mathbb{N} \subset \mathcal{A}= \bigcup_{n \in A}\{2n-1,2n\}$$

But then as $\mathbb{N}$ is infinite, there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$N=\max_{n \in A}+1$$
and

$$\{2N-1,2N\} \not\in \mathcal{A}$$
thus no finite sub cover exists and $(X,\tau)$ is not compact, as needed.

Comment: The definition of $\tau$ implies that $\{x\}\in\tau$ if $x$ is even. Any finite set is compact.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet so for $x$ even I can take $K=U=\{x\}$?

Comment: and for $x$ odd take $U=\{x,x+1\}$?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet

Comment: Yes.  The point is that if $x$ is even  and $U=\{x\},$ or if $x$ is odd and $U=\{x,x+1\}$ then in either case $U$ is a nbhd of $x$ and $U$ is a subset of every other nbhd of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

It is locally compact because ${2n-1, 2n}\$ is an open cover made of finite sets.

It is not compact because, for example:

1. The open cover $\{2n-1, 2n\}$ is an infinite open cover without subcover; or
2. The set of odd numbers is an infinite closed set (since the even are open) with discrete topology (therefore, not compact).